For a Wiener process $W(t)$, how to prove $dW(t)^2 = dt$?
In the book, Handbook of stochastic methods, it proves in section 4.2.5 that $\mathrm{d}W(t)^2 = \mathrm{d}t$. Here is a screen shot of this page. I cannot figure out why I can get (4.2.29) under some mild condition. Anyone has some ideas ?
Here, $W(t)$ is a Wiener process, $G(t)$ is a nonanticipating function, which means that for any $s, t$ and $t<s$, $G(t)$ is independent of $W(s)-W(t)$. The symbol $\langle\cdot\rangle$ means calulate the average of a random variable. ms-lim means the limit of mean square.


If $G\equiv 1$, can you prove it?

@Andrew Yes... It just came to me that, if $G(t)$ is bounded (some reasonably mild condition), $\Delta t_i^2$ can be regarded as $1/n^2$, it tends to zero more fastly when $n\rightarrow \infty$, so $I\rightarrow 0$.
